# Where is the Countdown Timer Image for ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04

I have been looking in ubuntu.com for the countdown timer to put in my website with no luck. Where is it since it is days left from release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.ubuntu.com/community/countdown

Comment: Thannk you but could you guide me step by step via the ubuntu wbepage on how you got there. I find the ubuntu page not very friendly when it comes to finding some things.

Comment: To be honest, I remember reading about them on http://omgubuntu.co.uk, so I went from there.